# Chrome does not render rotate if applied from javascript in <![CDATA[] > script tag inside an SVG

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, cdata

Hello i have a very odd problem. If i set the attribute "transformation" with the value "rotate(30, 3, 3)" with javascript from outside the SVG tag, chrome actually renders everything perfectly. But if i set a  tag inside the SVG and set the attribute from inside a  tag. The rotation does not get applied at all. Firefox has no problem with that.

Edit: I am sorry, i was tired last night. Of course i have to execute the function once the object is loaded. In my original document the whole thing is called way after the object is loaded. But thanks, now the fiddle is accurate.

Here is a fiddle to show, that what i am trying is actually valid:
https://jsfiddle.net/k7a5jg85/

Here is a fiddle to show the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/c2z29mhf/1/

```
<svg>
<script>
  <![CDATA[
    let rotationOffsetX = -20 + (30/2);
    let rotationOffsetY = -20;
    let rotationAngle = -(40 + 90);
    document.getElementById('barrel1').setAttribute("transform", 
      "rotate(" + 
      rotationAngle + ", " + 
      rotationOffsetX + ", " +
      rotationOffsetY + ")" );
  ]]>
</script>
  <svg data-kind="dummy" id="barrel1" x="0" y="0" width="2" height="15">
      <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="2" y2="7.5">
          <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#1E263C"/>
          <stop  offset="0.5355" style="stop-color:#AAAABE"/>
          <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#1E263C"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <rect fill="url(#SVGID_10_)" width="2" height="15"/>
      <rect y="15" fill="#1E263C" width="2" height="0.5"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you set the `type` attribute on the `<script>` tag to `application/javascript`?

Comment: ... Your real issue is that chrome doesn't apply the transformation on inner `<svg>` element, it has nothing to do with cdata nor js. Here is a real [MCVE]: https://jsfiddle.net/c2z29mhf/5

Comment: @Kaiido i would like to upvote you! This was exactly my problem. I mean i read your comment after i solved it but that's it!

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be seen in the javascript console:

```
 TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

You're executing the script before the `<svg>` element you are referencing has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but i am afraid that is not the real problem here. =( Still i updated the fiddle so it's accurate now. I also tried with and without the CDATA tags and it still doesn't work.